# Intellisense is not working for my User Defined Type in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, structure, user-defined-types

I made a structure:

```
Type AntennaParameters
    Private Model As String
    Private AntennaMasterName As String
    Private LowPorts As Integer
    Private MidPorts As Integer
    Private HighPorts As Integer
End Type
```

When I reference a variable of that type such as:

```
Dim struct As AntennaParameters
struct.Model
```

I don't see a list of all the variables inside that UDT. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: UDT members ought to be `Public`, and they are implicitly so. You are not seeing *IntelliSense* because the code isn't compiling (Debug > Compile VBAProject) =)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `Private` access modifier from each element. It is not a part of the syntax for making a vba `Type`

```
Type AntennaParameters
    Model As String
    AntennaMasterName As String
    LowPorts As Integer
    MidPorts As Integer
    HighPorts As Integer
End Type
```

Comment: Yep. `Public` or `Private` can precede the `Type` statement, but not the element types. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement) should be helpful to OP.